# Ubuntu 18.04 systemd-resolve doesn't read the /etc/resolv.conf properly

Tags: networking, dns, vpn, openvpn

I faced a strange issue with my Ubuntu 18.04. I use openfortivpn to connect to my company resources and it worked OK. I also use openvpn to connect to some different resources as well, sometimes even simultaneously.
Today all resources behind the vpn became unreachable and I figured out this is related to some DNS settings on my PC.

With no active openfortivpn connection:

```
ll /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Jan  9 10:52 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf

grep name /run/systemd/resolve/*.conf 
/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf:nameserver 192.168.139.2
/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf:nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

With active openfortivpn:

```
ll /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Jan  9 10:52 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf

grep name /run/systemd/resolve/*.conf 
resolv.conf:nameserver 192.168.139.2
stub-resolv.conf:nameserver 10.220.64.161
stub-resolv.conf:nameserver 10.220.64.162
```

As you can see, the openfortivpn has inserted 2 new nameservers into the `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` which is fine.
But seems like the `systemd-resolve` doesn't take this new config (no DNS server for `ppp0` interface) and internal resources behind the VPN were not reachable:

```
sudo systemd-resolve --status
Global
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 6 (ppp0)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 2 (ens33)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.139.2
          DNS Domain: localdomain
```

So I tried to add the DNS manually into the systemd-resolve:

```
sudo systemd-resolve --set-dns=10.220.64.161 --set-domain=localdomain --set-llmnr=yes --set-mdns=no --set-dnssec=no --interface=ppp0

systemd-resolve --status
Global
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 6 (ppp0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 10.220.64.161
          DNS Domain: localdomain

Link 2 (ens33)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.139.2
          DNS Domain: localdomain
```

And finally it works.
Any idea what is the problem here? Isn't this somehow related to `openvpn-systemd-resolved` because I can remember I installed this package recently in order to be able to use my other openvpn connections.

Thank you a lot for any advice.
Michal.

Answer (score 9):

using 18.10 I had a similar problem. I resolved my problem by modifying /etc/systemd/resolved.conf with the dns server and search domain information. this looks to be correct behavior, according to the man page,

> The DNS servers contacted are determined from the global settings in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf, the per-link static settings in /etc/systemd/network/*.network files (in case systemd-
> networkd.service(8) is used), the per-link dynamic settings received over DHCP, and any DNS server information made available by other system services. See resolved.conf(5) and systemd.network(5)
> for details about systemd's own configuration files for DNS servers. To improve compatibility, /etc/resolv.conf is read in order to discover configured system DNS servers, but only if it is not a
> symlink to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf or /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf (see below).

my config looks like this, adjust to fit your environment,

1. 192.168.1.1 is your private dns
2. domain syntax is important, don't forget the trailing dot "."

```
#/etc/systemd/resolved.conf
[Resolve]
DNS=192.168.1.1
#FallbackDNS=
Domains=blah.mydomain.com. blahblah.mydomain.com. 
#LLMNR=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
#Cache=yes
#DNSStubListener=yes
```

then restart the service

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service
```

verify service is running. syntax errors might cause issues that you can see here.

```
sudo systemctl status systemd-resolved.service
```

try to lookup a local domain

```
nslookup blah.mydomain.com
```

if that did not work, then verify the query does not time out. manually specify the dns server

```
nslookup blah.mydomain.com 192.168.1.1
```

resolved has a built-in query function which is helpful

```
% resolvectl query fedoraproject.org
fedoraproject.org: 2605:bc80:3010:600:dead:beef:cafe:fed9 -- link: enp5s0
                   2620:52:3:1:dead:beef:cafe:fed7 -- link: enp5s0
                   2610:28:3090:3001:dead:beef:cafe:fed3 -- link: enp5s0
                   2604:1580:fe00:0:dead:beef:cafe:fed1 -- link: enp5s0
                   2605:bc80:3010:600:dead:beef:cafe:feda -- link: enp5s0
                   2620:52:3:1:dead:beef:cafe:fed6 -- link: enp5s0
                   209.132.190.2               -- link: enp5s0
                   8.43.85.67                  -- link: enp5s0
                   38.145.60.21                -- link: enp5s0
                   67.219.144.68               -- link: enp5s0
                   140.211.169.196             -- link: enp5s0
                   140.211.169.206             -- link: enp5s0
                   152.19.134.142              -- link: enp5s0
                   38.145.60.20                -- link: enp5s0
                   152.19.134.198              -- link: enp5s0
                   8.43.85.73                  -- link: enp5s0

-- Information acquired via protocol DNS in 99.8ms.
-- Data is authenticated: no
```